# Conditional formatting for spaces in the List of Figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm trying to format the spaces between figure labels according to the figure number space, so that figures in the LOF appear like the following:

```
1 XXXXX

100  XXXXX
```

Instead of:

```
1    XXXXX

100  XXXXX
```

However, using `\if... \else` doesn't seem to work:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}{%
    \ifnum \c@figure< 99 \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}%
\else \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5.5em}%
\fi 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\addtocounter{figure}{99}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\ifthenelse{\c@figure<99}{...}{...}` with the `ifthen` package, to get rid of the error. But it seems that `\l@figure` is setted once for all entries.

Comment: You don't want to use \c@figure (which is probably 0 at this point).  You need to access the arguments then pass them on to \@docttedcline.

Comment: If you don't pass the arguments to \@dottedcline, you might need to end with `\expandafter\fi}`

Answer (score 1):

This was slightly complicated by the fact that the figure number was an argument of `\numberline`, not `\l@figure`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\tempfigure}{0}% reserve global name

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]% #1 = \numberline[number}{text}, #2 = page
{\bgroup
  \renewcommand{\numberline}[2]{\xdef\tempfigure{##1}}%
  {#1}% the rest is thrown away
\egroup
\ifnum \tempfigure< 99 \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}{#1}{#2}%
\else \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5.5em}{#1}{#2}%
\fi 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\addtocounter{figure}{99}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]