# How can I relocate a page number to the first line of each figure in list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a long caption of the figure and want to move it to the first line like the below example figure.

[image]

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\vskip \z@ \@plus .2\p@ 
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip 
\@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip \parindent #2\relax 
\@afterindenttrue \interlinepenalty \@M \leavevmode 
\@tempdima #3\relax 
\advance \leftskip \@tempdima \null \nobreak 
\hskip -\leftskip {#4}\nobreak
%%% dotfill here
\leaders \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
\hfill \nobreak 
\hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hfil \normalfont \normalcolor #5}\par }
\fi
}


\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{% #1 = \numberline[number}{text}, #2 = page
 \@dottedtocline{1}{2em}{3em}{#1}{#2}%
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question, but are you aware that you can do `\caption[short]{long}`, and then `long` will appear under the figure, but `short` will appear in the table of contents?  Also, your code example doesn't really help to generate the problem.

Comment: why are you putting large text in the page head???? You have not shown any code related to the individual items so hard to say what you should change. `\renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}` will break lots of things including `center` and `\item`

Comment: Anyway, the formatting for each entry is handled by `\l@figure`.  You will need to separate `\numberline{...}` from the rest of the entry.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387021/conditional-formatting-for-spaces-in-the-list-of-figures/387065?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C10.6708#387065 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution attempted  to emulate your requirements by defining a new list with the `tocloft` package.

The desired alignment for the page number is achieved by inserting the caption content into a `parbox` vertically top   aligned with the surrounding material, so that the page number is aligned with the first line of its content.
[image: r]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   

\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins

% ******************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tocloft}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\HeadCaptionfigures}{\begin{center}\Large List of Figures \end{center}
    \normalfont \normalsize Figure \hfill Page}

\newlistof{Fcaption}{blof}{\HeadCaptionfigures} % \newlistof{<entry>}{<file extension>}{<listofheader>}

\renewcommand{\cftFcaptiondotsep}{\cftnodots} % no dots
\renewcommand{\cftFcaptionafterpnum}{\vspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\cftFcaptionindent}{0.5em}% left indent
\addtolength{\cftFcaptionnumwidth}{0.5em} % space after figure number
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\makeatletter
\let\Oldcaption\caption
\newcommand{\Fcaption}[1]
{%
    \refstepcounter{Fcaption}
    \addcontentsline{blof}{Fcaption}
    {\protect\numberline{\thesection.\theFcaption}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\cftFcaptionindent-\cftFcaptionnumwidth-\@pnumwidth}{\ignorespaces#1}}
    \Oldcaption{#1}
}
\makeatother 
% *******************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \listofFcaption
    
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Figures}
    
    \begin{figure}[hb!]
        \Fcaption{The first caption}
    \end{figure}
    
    \clearpage  
    
    \clearpage  
    
    \begin{figure}
        \Fcaption{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
            practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
            in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
            used as a canon for our understanding.}
    \end{figure}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{figure}
        \Fcaption{The last caption}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

**OPTION** A similar approach, but without using additional packages. We patched the `\caption` command, so it works also for `\listoftables.`

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins

% ******************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter    
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}

\renewcommand\listoffigures{% header of list to figures
    \begin{center}\bfseries \Large List of Figures \end{center}
    \normalfont \normalsize Figure \hfill Page\vspace*{1ex} 
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%     
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}

\newcommand{\@leftindent}{0.5em}% left indent = 0.5em  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\@numberwidth}{2.3em} % figure or table number allocated width <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{\@leftindent}{\@numberwidth}} 
\let\l@table\l@figure
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} 
\xpatchcmd{\@caption}{\ignorespaces #2}%
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@pnumwidth-\@tocrmarg-\@numberwidth}\ignorespaces#2\vspace*{0.5ex}\end{minipage}}
{}{}
\makeatother
% ******************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\begin{document}        
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \clearpage
    
    \listoftables
    
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Figures}
    
    \begin{figure}[hb!]
    \caption{The first figure caption}
    \end{figure}
    
    \clearpage  

    \begin{figure}
    \caption{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
    practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
    in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
    used as a canon for our understanding.}
    \end{figure}
        
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{The last figure caption}
    \end{figure}
    
    \clearpage
    \section{Tables}
    
    \begin{table}[hb!]
        \caption{The first table caption}
    \end{table}
    
    \clearpage  
    
    \clearpage  
    
    \begin{table}
        \caption{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
            practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
            in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
            used as a canon for our understanding.}
    \end{table}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{table}
        \caption{The last table caption}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```